# jquery hide div's click function, then bring back when clicking same link

Tags: jquery, function, click, addclass, var

I am using the following script to do the following:

1. When clicking **a.navbar-toggle.search** it drops down & shows the **.search-wrapper** div
2. When it shows the **.search-wrapper** div, it also add's a class (hide) to the following divs to hide them:

*.strapline-top / .container.inner / .gallery/ .boxes*

The above is all fine & working well.

After clicking the link it changes it to:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-toggle search show">
```

*Question:*

What I need now is to show/bring back the above divs (in point 2) when the following div is clicked:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-toggle search show">
```

jQuery script being used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function ($) {
    var search_wrapper = $('.search-wrapper');
     $('a.navbar-toggle.search').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('show');
        $('.strapline-top').addClass('hide');
        $('.container.inner').addClass('hide');
        $('.gallery').addClass('hide');
        $('.boxes').addClass('hide');
        search_wrapper.slideToggle(400);
        if ( $(this).hasClass('show') ) {
            $('a.navbar-toggle.user').removeClass('show'); // mark the other as hidden
            mywinkworth_wrapper.slideUp(400); // hide the other one
        }
        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/cuxrtd1d/4/)

Comment: could u provide a fiddle mate..It would be lot easier

Comment: Hi There... I have added a JSfiddle above in the original post

Comment: Update JSfiddle as wasn't hiding other div's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what u need mate.. :)

```
$(function ($) {
    var search_wrapper = $('.search-wrapper');
     $('a.navbar-toggle.search').click(function () {
        $('.strapline-top,.container.inner,.gallery,.boxes').toggle();
        search_wrapper.slideToggle(400);
         if ( $(this).is(':visible') ) {
            $('a.navbar-toggle.user').toggle();; // this is changing another div's class - mark the other as hidden
            mywinkworth_wrapper.slideUp(400); // for the above - hide the other one
        }
        return false;
    });
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eboad30b/)

**FYI**

[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: Many thanks... not exactly what I wanted - but it showed me where I was going wrong - the '.toggle' ;-)